# Problem in Pocketsphinx demo on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice, offline-mode

I try to download and run the offline voice recognization demo from this link - http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/ . I m successfully install and run this demo project on device, but when i push and hold the button and when i release the button, it try to convert into text. The textfield "Your text goes here" becomes empty but it is not displaying the any result, i.e. Text of What we speak.

Please any one who run this demo successfully, help me with better suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the text field stays blank when there is some error in the configuration for the native pocket sphinx code. Any errors encountered by PocketSphinx should be printed to the log file. Figure out where your PocketSphinx log file is; it is set using the `setLogfile(String path)` function. One of the things that happens to me quite often is a mismatch between the words in the dictionary and the words in the language model/grammar. Since you probably haven't edited those, I'd say it could be a wrong path to one of them. The log file will tell you about anything that couldn't be loaded.